# Slight Slip on motorcycle braking

Tags: motorcycle, tires, slipping

Four months ago i bought a used motorcycle (FZ8 Fazer non ABS model) with 5000km on it. These kilometers were traveled by the previous owner in a period of about 4 years (VERY light use) and for the last 12months before i bought it, it was almost not used. Since then (4 months) i 've made another 6000km on it with no issues at all. I knew in advance that at some point i would have to change the tires since their rubber would be dried and stiff but since i consider my self an experienced driver (with over 200k km in my history) and since the last four months was a quite warm period (summer in Greece) with temperatures about +30C i decided to use the old ones at least until winter. 
Roads in Greece tend to be very dry throughout most of the year with quite warm surface and still quite slippery, especially in urban areas. 
Once again i would notice that i have quite an experience with the bike and i am able to perform more "extreme" handling on it. 
The last month i had three cases of slip on my front tire all on moderate braking application all of which i was able to handle quite easy and avoid any fall. I will anyway change my tires very soon but i would like to know if this is mostly due to temperature changes from the upcoming winter or due to some rubber property which was not so obvious after riding again with these tires but after 6000km is now more obvious.

Any ideas???

Edit (to clarify further):
1) I know and completely understand the risks of riding with these tires so please lets move on to the QUESTION.
2) The tires ARE the stock ones, so yes they are even older (about 2012)
3) They WERE properly (as much possible) stored and they had NO cracks or traceable issues (i had a test ride to decide if i should immediately change them)
4) They STILL don't have any (current excluded) after 6000km
5) Their traction-cornering behavior (after getting a little warmed up) is quite impressive to me given all of the above info

Maybe i should move over to chemistry.stackexchange.com !?

Comment: An experienced rider would not be using and trusting their life to degraded tires - otherwise known as “ditch-finders”...

Comment: I think the answers are assuming that the tires are degraded, however is this a good assumption @kokobill? Do you see cracks in the tires or other visible signs of degradation? If so please post.

Comment: 4 years old tires which have been sitting not being properly stored are degraded without a doubt, especially if these are the stock tires (5K km bike) which might be even older since bikes do not get sold the day after they get out of production and the tires themselves are not fit right after production.

Remember that 5 years old tires are considered trash and should not be used.

Comment: I agree @AzirisMorora. I'm not making the assumption that they are the original tires, which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this question was downvoted? It is a *reasonable* question, whether you agree/disagree with what is being asked.

Comment: @GdD Well, he said himself " I knew in advance that at some point i would have to change the tires since their rubber would be dried and stiff", which tells me that the tires have not been changed.

Comment: The OP made an *assumption* that I'm challenging @AzirisMorora. Maybe the tires are in need of replacement, or maybe they are newer and something else is causing the slip. GdG's first rule of troubleshooting is to always test assumptions.

Comment: Let's just wait for OP to answer then, it is not an assumption that you will have to change 4 years old tires that have not been used enough.
@kokobill, care to join us ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't really say without being there and being experienced, you should be able to tell.

I can see three easy reasons :

- A little bit too much pressure on used tires
- Used tires having a lower heat threshold and so getting more slippery under heavy use
- Something on the road, a little oil spot, some light rain making hydrocarbons come on top of the road, gravel...

No doubt you can handle a normal slippage, however, in an emergency situation, like a car cutting me off, I want to know I can trust my bike.

Comment: I failed to note that i checked the pressure and it's within the given measurements. the question is WHAT is causing this cahnge in behavior. (temperature changes or due some rubber property which is now more "exposed" after 6000km)

Comment: To me it's a simple case of you getting used to the bike and using it a little bit harder or the weather getting the road warmer, making the tire itself too hot.
After a given temperature, every tires will lose it's gripping action and get more and more slippery.
This is due to the fact that tires are polymer, which under heat decompose.
That is also why after too quick heat and cool cycles, tires will crack.

Comment: About the "an emergency situation" I should note that I live in Greece. In most (if not all) urban areas the road quality would cause an emergency handling to fail. I have already checked this many times with new tires AND with my bicycle so i wound not want to know the actual outcome.

Comment: Time to go supermoto then ! :)

Answer (score 5):

Riding on old, degraded tires is extremely dangerous. If you are experiencing slipping under moderate braking, imagine what happens during an emergency stop. You should change them immediately.

Comment: I am well aware of all this as mentioned above. Yet this does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @kokobill It does provide an answer to the question. The tires are slipping because they're old. That you see no cracks is irrelevant; the rubber in tires degrades with age, they become less resilient, and they don't grip as well. Replace them.